# C Language, a Structure of Files

Tags: c, computer-science, codeblocks

I am attempting to create a struct which contains two file pointers. (See Below)

```
    typedef struct dataFiles
    {
        FILE * inputSet;
        FILE * outputSet;
    }fData;
```

I would like to be able to use this to use a function to open and close the files, I have one right here:

```
    void openFiles(struct dataFiles * fiData)
    {
        fiData->inputSet = fopen("inputfile.txt","r");
        fiData->outputSet = fopen("outputfile.txt","o");
        return fiData;
    }
```

In the main function I first declare the struct as:

```
    fdata * fileData;
```

then try and access it via:

```
    openFiles(&fileData);
```

my program runs and compiles, but I am having issues getting the data from the inputfile into the struct, when I check my output, it's all 0's. Any general tips on how to implement this type of code would be appreciated. (Note: This is a question in relation to a School Assignment, However, I have already met the requirements for the assignment and am merely interested in this for my own curiosity)~Thanks!

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining (at least warnings) about at least two things from the code you posted - trying to return a non-void expression for a `void` function and passing the wrong kind of pointer to `openFiles()`. Not to mention the typo in the `fileData` declaration.

Comment: as a side note, unless you're opening only an ascii file you should add the "b" flag to fopen. i.e. use `fopen(filename, "rb")`. The difference is that you will get an EOF early on files without it.

Comment: Does your program compiles without warnings?
TIP: Never ignore compiler warning!

Comment: If you're compiling from the command line add the flag `-Wall`. E.g. `gcc -Wall -o out file.c`

Answer (score 1):

declare it like:

```
fdata fileData; //This memory is on the stack, not the heap
```

Memory can be in two places, on the stack and in the heap. Memory on the stack doesnt need to be allocated, you just need to get the reference to it. Hence doing, `&fileData` will get you the pointer you need. However, you cannot return a pointer to data on the stack. Therefore, you need a pointer to the heap. To create a pointer to memory in the heap you call malloc with the size of the memory that you need. In this case it is `malloc(sizeof(fileData))`. This returns a void* which you will need to cast to a fileData*.

also change

```
 void openFiles(struct dataFiles * fiData)
```

to

```
 fData openFiles(struct dataFiles * fiData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather declare it as

```
fdata fileData;
```

then

```
openFiles(&fileData);
```

If you declared `fileData` as a `fdata *` then `&fileData` would be of type `fdata **` which would not match your function parameter's type.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing pointers with variables. For your function to work, you should declare fileData as follows:

```
fdata fileData;
```

(without the pointer), and remove the `return` in `openFiles`. It is not needed as the argument is modified by reference.

Answer (score 0):

You have type problem. `openFiles` should get `fData*` , but you pass `fData**` to it.
you should do something like:

```
fileData=malloc(sizeof(fData));
openFiles(fileData);
```

edit: or just change the type to `fileData` to `fData`, and pass its address.